# How to name a dataframe so that I can look for it within a list

Tags: r, purrr

I have a function that returns a dataframe. I use this function with `furrr::future_map2` so that I get a list with several dataframes.

- What I want is the ability to use the `name` input in the function to name the dataframe so that I can search the return list by name.

#### example

```
test <- function(x, name){
   require(tidyverse)
   z <- data.frame(x+1) %>% stats::setNames(., "a")

   return(z)
 }


furrr::future_map2(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"), ~test(.x, .y))
```

- The first df within the list would be `a`, the second `b` and so on
- The naming should be done within the function
- The option of `names(list.return) <- vector.of.list.names.in.character` does NOT work for me.

Please help

Comment: You are not passing `name` into `test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DavisVaughan provided the solution
https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/10

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
mapply(
  function(x,y){
    data.frame(y+1) %>% setNames(., x)
    }, 
  c("a", "b", "c"), 1:3, USE.NAMES = T, SIMPLIFY = F)
```

**Output is:**

```
$a
  a
1 2

$b
  b
1 3

$c
  c
1 4
```

Comment: I wanted to use future_map2 for this. It speeds-up my read times, from 31 mins to 6 mins!

Comment: Was this benchmarking done between `mapply` & `furrr`? btw we are happy to know that you found a solution using `names(res) <- purrr::map_chr(res, ~attr(.x, "name"))`.

Comment: I have not done the benchmarking. I never learned `mapply`, I concentrated my efforts in `purrr`, I could not understand the `apply` group of function despite my best efforts :(